# Sum two columns in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new in laravel, so I have a little problem with sum of two columns from same table.

My response should be two decimal number for column sum(dug) and column sum(pot). Addition and subtraction and other operation between those columns doesn't matter. I just want sum(dug) and sum(pot)...

My code is:

```
 public function getBalance() {
    $details = AnalyticalCard::select('sum(dug) as duguje, sum(pot) as potrazuje')
        ->where('firma', 001)
        ->where('komitent', 'V003')
        ->where('konto', 2020)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($details);
}
```

My SQL query is:

```
select 
    sum(dug) as duguje, sum(pot) as potrazuje 
from 
    fn_promet 
where 
    firma = 001 and komitent = 'V003' and konto = '2020'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selectRaw`. Here is an adapted example:

```
    public function getBalance() {
    $details = DB::table('table')->selectRaw('sum(dug) as duguje, sum(pot) as potrazuje')
        ->where('firma', 001)
        ->where('komitent', 'V003')
        ->where('konto', 2020)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($details);
```

Comment: tnx, i will use this query

Answer (score 0):

your query should be

```
$details = AnalyticalCard::select('sum(dug) as duguje, sum(pot) as potrazuje')
        ->where('firma', 001)
        ->where('komitent', 'V003')
        ->where('konto', 2020)
    ->select(DB::Raw('sum(dug) as duguje, SUM(pot) as potrazuje '))
        ->get();
```

Comment: txn, great solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getBalance() {
    
    $details = AnalyticalCard::select(DB::raw('SUM(dug) as duguje'),DB::raw('SUM(pot) as potrazuje'))
        ->where('firma', 001)
        ->where('komitent', 'V003')
        ->where('konto', 2020)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($details);
}
```